# javascript - understanding how css classes change / update

Tags: javascript, html, css, classname

I have a div with id="mydiv" it is not assigned to a class at the beginning.
The following two functions assign classes to the mydiv.

```
function one(){
document.getElementById(mydiv).setAttribute("class", "classone");
}

function two(){
document.getElementById(mydiv).setAttribute("class", "classtwo");
}
```

After these two functions are completed what is the className of mydiv?
Is it classtwo or classone and classtwo both?
(If it is both classes - how can I change function two to ;

1. first delete the current className of the mydiv
2. then assign the className (the code I have already mentioned in the function)
   )

Comment: If you set it to a string, it's going to be that string. The previous value will be erased. If you want to *add* a class, you have to fetch the current value of the attribute and add another string. Note that you don't have to use `.setAttribute()` - you can reference the class string directly via the "className" property of the DOM element in question.

Comment: to add a class (and only a class), you can use elm.className+=" "+strClassToAdd; to manage, use the newer elm.classList.remove('classone'); elm.classList.add('classtwo');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After these two functions are completed what is the className of mydiv? Is it classtwo or classone and classtwo both?

It will be "classtwo". Did you check?

> If it is both classes…

It isn't, the previous value is replaced by the new one. As pointed out in the comments, if you just want to **replace** the value it's easier to use the *className* property:

```
document.getElementById(mydiv).className = "classone";
```

and to **add** a class value, use:

```
document.getElementById(mydiv).className += " classtwo";
```

note the leading space. And to remove all class values:

```
document.getElementById(mydiv).className = "";
```

There is also a [WHATWG *classList* API](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#dom-classlist) that is also [documented at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList), however support may be lacking in some browsers so not safe to use on the general web yet.

Answer (score 1):

Without using jQuery's `addClass` etc., and if you don't want to or can't use `classList`, you can handle this yourself with something like:

```
function addClass(elt, cls) {
    elt.className += " " + cls;
}
```

That runs the risk of adding the same class twice, which won't cause any harm, but is inelegant. To avoid that problem:

```
function addClass(elt, cls) {
    var classes = elt.className.split(/\s+/),
        index = classes.indexOf(cls);

    if (index === -1) {
        elt.className = classes.concat(cls).join(' ');
    }
}
```

Similar logic can be used to implement `removeClass`:

```
function removeClass(elt, cls) {
    var classes = elt.className.split(/\s+/),
        index = classes.indexOf(cls);

    if (index !== -1) {
        classes.splice(index, 1);
        elt.className = classes.join(' ');
    }
}
```